# Volver a otras ventanas

Tags: java

Tengo lo siguinte:

```
    JButton btnSalir = new JButton("Volver");
    btnSalir.setBounds(469, 674, 89, 23);
    btnSalir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            Administrador Admin = new Administrador();
            Admin.setVisible(true);

            ModificarEmpleados.this.dispose();
            setVisible(false);


        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnSalir);
```

Esto me funciona y vuelve a la ventana administrador, el tema es que necesito que, si lo abre de la ventana administrador, vuelva a administrador, como lo hace, pero si lo abren de la ventana operador vuelva a operador sin que deje de ir a la de administrador.

Answer (score 1):

Para volver atrás puedes cerrar la ventana utilizando el método `finalize()`. De esa manera no importa en que ventana estés siempre volverás a la anterior.

```
btnSalir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        finalize();

    }
});
```

Comment: No me estaría funcionando de esa manera, me pide que lo ponga en un try, lo puse y tampoco, no hace nada.

Comment: Que error te presenta?

Comment: No me da ningún error, lo que pasa es que no funciona directamente, no hace nada. Gracias por la ayuda! Lo que hice al final fue crear una ventana distinta para cada caso, queda des prolijo pero era una salida rápida! Gracias !!